# Vue datepicker change value to string

Tags: date, vue.js, datepicker

I use [vuejs-datepicker](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker). I try add to value string, but input is empty, I can only add date:

```
<datepicker :value="getDateDB"></datepicker>

getDateDB(){
    if (getDate == 'no_date') {
        return 'No date';
    } else {
        return new Date(date);
    }
}
```

I found this description in documencation vuejs-datepicker:

```
Prop    Type          Description
value   Date|String   Date value of the datepicker
```

**How I can add to `:value` string ?**

Comment: I believe what they are referring to, in terms of the type of the value, is that it can either be of type `Date` or a date string - as in the string value as returned by `Date()`.

Answer (score 0):

the datepicker is ok, you problem should be in your method, make the method computed if is not and the variable getDate maybe is `'undefined'`, maybe should be `this.getDate`

Comment: No, because when I change my method to: `<datepicker :value="xxxxxx" </datepicker>` and I add to data: `xxxxxx: 'aaaa',` input in datapicker in empty, but when I change: `xxxxxx: '2019-01-01',` in input I see date 1 Jan 2019. So I can't add to `:value` string

Comment: ok, im comfused, do you want to hide the component when getDate is empty?

Comment: No I want add to value in input datapicker string "no date"

Comment: ok, the placeholder works for you?  `:placeholder="getDateDB=='No date'?'No date':''"`